# AWS CloudFormation create RDS cluster and add its ARN to a policy in the same template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-policies

I'm creating an `RDS cluster` and, in the same template, a policy with some permissions to allow particular actions over that cluster.

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Actions:
      - 'rds-data:BatchExecuteStatement'
      - 'rds-data:ExecuteStatement'
    Resource: 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:1111111111:cluster:production-mycluster-rdscluster-no1yzvzs29sq'
```

The problem is that `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` does not support `Fn::GetAtt ARN`, and, since RDS add that random string at the end of the ARN, in this example *no1yzvzs29sq* I don't know how can I use something like a wildcard to "whitelist" part of the name.

I would like something like 
`arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:1111111111:cluster:production-mycluster-rdscluster-*`

But it doesn't work. I will appreciate help!

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **construct the ARN** based on the Cluster name yourself.

For example:

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Actions:
      - 'rds-data:BatchExecuteStatement'
      - 'rds-data:ExecuteStatement'
    Resource: !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:rds:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster:${MyDBCluster}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonrdsdataapi.html#amazonrdsdataapi-resources-for-iam-policies):

> Amazon RDS Data API does not support specifying a resource ARN in the `Resource` element of an IAM policy statement. To allow access to Amazon RDS Data API, specify `“Resource”: “*”` in your policy.

So at this point it looks like you're stuck with a policy that looks like

```yaml
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Actions:
      - 'rds-data:BatchExecuteStatement'
      - 'rds-data:ExecuteStatement'
    Resource: '*'
```